# Why do we set the similarity function at index time in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

How does Lucene use Similarity during indexing time? I understand the role of similarity while reading the index. So, `searcher.setSimilarity()` makes sense in scoring. What is the use of `IndexWriterConfig.setSimilarity()`?

Answer (score 0):

***How does Lucene use Similarity during indexing time?***

The short answer is: Lucene captures some statistics at indexing time which can then be used to support scoring at query time. I expect it is simply a matter of efficiency that these are captured as part of the indexing process, rather than being repeatedly re-computed on the fly, when running queries.

There is a section in the [`Similarity`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html) javadoc which describes this at a high level:

> *At indexing time, the indexer calls [`computeNorm(FieldInvertState)`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html#computeNorm-org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInvertState-), allowing the Similarity implementation to set a per-document value for the field that will be later accessible via LeafReader.getNormValues(String).*

The javadoc goes on to describe further details - for example:

> *Many formulas require the use of average document length, which can be computed via a combination of CollectionStatistics.sumTotalTermFreq() and CollectionStatistics.docCount().*

So, for example, the [segment info](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene86/Lucene86SegmentInfoFormat.html) file within a Lucene index records the number of documents in each segment.

There are other statistics which can be captured in an index to support scoring calculations at query time. You can see a summary of these stats in the [Index Structure Overview](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene87/package-summary.html#Overview) documentation - with links to further details.

***What is the use of IndexWriterConfig.setSimilarity()?***

This is a related question which follows on from the above points.

By default, Lucene uses the [`BM25Similarity`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/BM25Similarity.html) formula.

That is one of a few different scoring models that you may choose to use (or you can define your own). The `setSimilarity()` method is how you can choose a different similarity (scoring model) from the default one. This means different statistics may need to be captured (and then used in different ways) to support the chosen scoring model.

It would not make sense to use one scoring model at indexing time, and a different one at query time.

(Just to note: I have never set the similarity scoring model myself - I have always used the default model.)

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question.